# R remove saturday and sunday from weekly seasonality analysis with prophet

Tags: r

Using the prophet library I am able to extract the weekly seasonality.

```
library("prophet")

history <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2016-01-01'), by = 'd'),y = sin(1:366/200) + rnorm(366)/10)

m <- prophet(history)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)
```

But this analysis includes Saturdays and Sundays even when the underlying data does not include these day. What parameters do I need to add to the prophet function to exclude Sat and Sun?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an option in the `prophet` package to remove weekends but you can use the `weekdays` function in base `R` to determine what weekday a date is and then exclude Saturday and Sunday, for example, with `dplyr`:

```
history <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2016-01-01'), by = 'd'),y = sin(1:366/200) + rnorm(366)/10)
nrow(history)
#> [1] 366

library(dplyr)
history_week <- history %>% 
  mutate(wd = weekdays(ds)) %>% 
  filter(wd != c("Saturday", "Sunday"))
nrow(history_week)
#> [1] 314
```

Comment: EDIT: Misread your code and am now noticing you are modifying the 'history' variable.?

I think the OP is stating that the history already does not contain weekends. He would like Prophet to not predict for Weekends as well (since the history data does not contain those days either).